# Django error with TypeError: must be unicode not str

Tags: python, django, signals, slug

I have been having some issues when migrating my django project into heroku. I am getting the error below when performing a heroku run python manage.py syncdb and then typing the superuser and password.

```
 File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/text.py", line 409, in slugify
    value = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', value).encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')
TypeError: must be unicode, not str
```

my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from autoslug import AutoSlugField


# Create your models here.
class Profile(models.Model):
    account = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 120, null=True, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length = 120, null=True, blank=True)
    website = models.CharField(max_length = 120, null=True, blank=True)
    bio = models.CharField(max_length = 120, null=True, blank=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = False, auto_now_add=True)
    updated_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True, auto_now_add=False)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from="account")

    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('view_profile', None, {'username': self.account.username})

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.account.username)

# here is the profile model
def user_post_save(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    """Create a user profile when a new user account is created"""
    if created == True:
        p = Profile()
        p.account = instance
        p.save()

post_save.connect(user_post_save, sender=User)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use `AutoSlugField` on a relation field. You can only `AutoSlugField` on attributes that return text, not another model instance. Create a property that returns what element of the user you slugify:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from="_accountname")
    # [....]

    @property
    def _accountname(self):
        return self.account.username
```

On a separate note: your `__unicode__` method *must* return a `unicode` object, but yours returns a `str` object instead:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return str(self.account.username)
```

Remove the `str()` call:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.account.username
```

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the unicode function on your Profile model to the following:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return u'%s' % self.account.username
```

Comment: `self.account.username` is *already* a unicode value. And if it wasn't, you could just use `unicode(self.account.username)`.

Comment: I tried this, it didn't work. I will try the answer from @MartijnPieters

Comment: @cloudviz: you didn't include your whole traceback, so I had to do some guessing; Pierre did too and didn't guess correctly. Lesson learned: include the whole traceback next time.